# Gurobi - declare constrains in python

Tags: python, gurobi

I'm trying to declare the constraints below in Python but it does not work.

This is my code:

```
m.addConstrs((tsk*Xkt[i]).sum(k, '*') + (tbk*Qkt[i]).sum(k, "*") <= bt[i]+Ot[i] for i in range(0, t))
```

[image]

Comment: this is _not_ your code. This is a _line_ of your code. Please provide a [mcve] and the exact error.

Comment: Sorry for terminology. Error is so long that I did not want to paste it here. and the end it says only "KeyError: 0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tupledict.sum()` method applies to a `tupledict` object, not a `LinExpr` such as `tsk*Xkt[i]`.  You have two alternatives:

1. Use the `sum()` or `quicksum()` function, creating an expression like:

   ```
   m.addConstrs(quicksum(ts[k]*X[k,t] + tb[k]*Q[k,t] for k in Krange) <= b[t]+O[t] for t in Trange)
   ```
2. Use the `tupledict.prod()` method:

   ```
   m.addConstrs(X.prod(ts, '*', t) + Q.prod(tb, '*', t) <= b[t]+O[t] for t in Trange)
   ```

A few comments:

1. I changed your subscript notation to better match the mathematical expressions.  I am not clear whether the expressions are ts and tb or t ˙ s and t ˙ b; adjust your code accordingly.
2. There is currently a documentation bug in the syntax for `tupledict.prod()`; my code above reflects the correct use of this method.

Comment: Thank you so much for help! I chose quiksum - done the job well!